# Need explanation about Kivy Rules [ closed ]

Tags: python, kivy, rules

currently i am learning Kivy , and i have read the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html) about the kv lang. but i don't really understand about the kv rule :

want to ask :

- what is root rule
- how to declare the root rule and where
- can give some examples : ) ?

like : in .kv file

```
#:kivy 2.0.0

<main>: ----------------------------------------- <-- class rule
    Label: -------------------------------------- <-- root rule
        text: "Hello World !"                     <-- child of  Label
        font_size: 70                             <-- child of  Label
        center_x: root.width /2                   <-- child of  Label
        center_y: root.height /2                  <-- child of  Label

    BoxLayout: ---------------------------------- <-- root rule
        size: root.width /2, root.height /3       <-- child of  BoxLayout

        Button:                                   <-- child of  BoxLayout
            text: "Button 1"                      <-- child of  Button
            font_size: 30                         <-- child of  Button

        Button:                                   <-- child of  BoxLayout
            text: "Button 2"                      <-- child of  Button
            font_size: 30                         <-- child of  Button
```

is it sth like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite. The `<main>` is a root rule, but it is not a `root widget`, and the `Label` and `BoxLayout` are children of an instance of the class named `main`. Any use of `root` (as in `root.xxx`) inside the `<main>` rule is a reference to that instance of `main`. Note that rules enclosed in `<>` can be considered to be descriptions of how to build an instance of the class named within the `<>`. Such a rule does not itself trigger the creation of a widget.

Not well explained in the documentation is that there is also the possibility of a `root widget` in the `kv`. For example:

```
main:
    Label:
        text: "Hello World !"
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width /2
        center_y: root.height /2
```

Here `main` is a root rule (since it has no indentation), and it is also a `root widget`, because it has no surrounding `<>`. Only one `root widget` is allowed. This is typically used to define the `root widget` of an application. Using `app.root` anywhere in the `kv` (not limited to inside the above rule) will refer to the `root widget` instance. When this rule is loaded, it will produce an instance of class `main` with the children as described in the rule.

As an aside, classes referenced in `kv` should be capitalized. Not capitalizing class names in `kv` can cause unexpected errors.

Comment: oic ~ i get a better understanding of how kivy rules work now : ) thanks for the explanation : )

Comment: aside , want to ask about the `canvas`  really dk how it works : (

Comment: This isn't the place for a course on kivy, but start with [this](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/drawing.html).